# Validation Group in ASP.NET 1.1

Tags: asp.net, validationgroup

I have 2 buttons which validates different sets of textboxes (which have corresponding asp validators). How can I control the validations triggered by each button?

Comment: ASP CODE:
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="Validator1" runat="server" Font-Size="8pt" Font-Names="Arial"
ControlToValidate="txtPrice" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Please enter the Price"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:button id="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add/Update"></asp:button>
<asp:button id="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete"></asp:button></TD>

Comment: Please note that I'm using ASP 1.1. I cant utilize the validationgroup property

Answer (score 0):

Add ValidationGroup="set1" and ValidationGroup="set2" properties to your textboxes, buttons, Validators and Validation Summaries, that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the same Group name for each set of textbox and buttons .

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="GroupOne"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"         
ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
ErrorMessage="ErrorMessageForTextBox1" ValidationGroup="GroupOne">   
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>  

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="GroupOne" />

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" ValidationGroup="GroupTwo"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server"        
ControlToValidate="TextBox2"
ErrorMessage="ErrorMessageForTextBox1" ValidationGroup="GroupTwo">   
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

For ASP version  1.1 , use this [link](http://aspalliance.com/699_Solving_the_Challenges_of_ASPNET_Validation.4) !